# module load - how to load modulefiles

Tags: load, environment-modules, modulefile

I am trying to replicate a tutorial on my Ubuntu 18.04.

There are two lines:
`module load dev/python/2.7.6`
`module load stats/R/3.2.1-Cairo`

I am not quite sure how to load modules. I tried downloading http://modules.sourceforge.net/.

I am not sure how to do so. If I am correct I may need to download the module files myself. Does anyone know where I can do so?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 you could easily install environment-modules from the official Ubuntu package repository. For instance from a terminal with `apt-get` command:

`apt-get install environment-modules`

If you start a new terminal afterwards, you should get the `module` command available from your default shell.

Modulefiles do not come along with the `module` command. They are generally provided by the third-party handling the installation of the software that need to be activated though modulefile.

In your situation, I imagine you should get these modulefiles from your tutorial. Or you are expected to connect to a given system providing these modulefiles.